Automatically Hides Rows with Cell Value 1 Error
I am using this script to automatically hide those rows with cell value 1 on it. Originally it is located in Column A (Sample A) but when I tried to move it on Col B (Sample B), it stopped working. How do I fix this?
function HideRowsEqualTo1Only() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var values = range.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] == 1) { // Assuming the values you want to check are in the first column
      sheet.hideRows(i + 1); // Rows are indexed starting from 1
    } else {
      sheet.showRows(i + 1); // Unhide rows not equal to 1
    }
  }
} 




About Originally it is located in Column A (Sample A) but when I tried to move it on Col B (Sample B), it stopped working. and your showing script, please modify it as follows.
From:
if (values[i][0] == 1) {

To:
if (values[i][1] == 1) {


By this modification, the values of column "B" are checked. Is this modification your expected result?

As another modification, in your situation, the following modification might also be able to be used. In this modification, first, all rows of the data range are shown. And, the specific rows are hidden in the loop.
function HideRowsEqualTo1Only() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  sheet.showRows(1, values.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][1] == 1) {
      sheet.hideRows(i + 1);
    }
  }
} 



